# Session expiration not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm trying to expire a trial user's session after a fixed timeperiod of logging in. All the examples I've looked at so far use the session[:expires_at] key like this:

```
    session[:expires_at] = Time.now + 100
```

But this seems to do nothing when I try it on my app. I inspect the cookie and the expires header is still set to "Session". Refreshing the page also confirms this suspicion.

I realise that there are other ways to configure the site-wide session duration but I don't want to make a sitewide change. I just want a specific scenario to be configured with this session duration.

My guess is that an after_filter in the Rails stack is resetting the expires_header but I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this before and I can't find any documentation for it. I would imagine you would have to implement something in the application controller that checks if the `session[:expire_at]` that you're setting has passed by.