# Rails cookie based sessions: mixing session scope with expiration times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

So I've asked this question in a different way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712968/session-expiration-not-working-in-rails/14713390#14713390) and got no answers so I'm going to try to rephrase it, since this seems to be a very simple issue.

I have a Rails app with cookie based sessions. By default they don't have any expires_at timestamps and so the scope of the session cookie is 'session'. This is your vanilla Rails sessions stuff.

Now I want to create a 'demo user' functionality wherein I kick the user out after 15 mins. To accomplish this, I want to set an expires_at on the session cookie for Time.now + 15.minutes

```
 session[:expires_at] = Time.now + 15.minutes
```

Now this above piece of code does execute, but it has no impact on the cookie's scope. The scope remains 'session'. How do I change the scope from being 'session' to being a datetime?

If I configure my entire application's Session in the production.rb to be

```
 :expire_after =>  24.hours
```

Then it will work... but the problem is that I want to selectively control the expiration date on the session cookie.

**Edit**: Turns out that the reason why there is no impact on the cookie's scope when I set the session[:expires_at] is because subsequent requests are clobbering the session cookie and resetting it back to session. Still not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps instead of relying on cookie expiry (see section 2.9 in ["Ruby On Rails Security Guide"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) on why it is bad), similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3), store timestamp when session was created in the session itself (say `session[:created_at]`) and then check on each request if it needs to be expired for these 'demo users':

```
before_filter :check_session

def check_session
  # TODO: check session validity
  if session[:demo_user] && session[:created_at] > 15.minutes.ago
    reset_session
    # TODO: redirect to login page
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this solution for what the OP is describing. It will definitely do what you're asking, avoid dealing with cookie expiry, and gives you 100% control over when to expire demo sessions.

Answer (score 0):

While not the very elegant way, but this works for a single session:

```
...
request.env['rack.session.options'] = {expire_after: 15.minutes}
session[:user_id] = 1
...
```