# Configure multiple named sessions in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I have a Rails 5 app that uses the default session store for user authentication through Devise as well as a custom session controller set up to handle access to other resources for unauthenticated users.

The trouble is that although the sessions work properly, the application will create both cookies irrespective of the controller requiring it and end the Devise session after 30 minutes. I am looking for some guidance on how to add a custom session and configure it correctly in Rails.

My incorrect session store config:

```
#/config/initializers/session_store.rb

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_application_session'
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'custom_session', expire_after: 30.minutes
```

Is this something that needs to be addressed in middleware?

Comment: I believe that devise is been stored on the custom_session, you should deal with that one at the controller level, try to test it, delete your cookies and sessions and check if they both are been created on the first load

Comment: thanks you are correct, and the custom session would overwrite the app session when created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional trial and error I moved the session expiry logic into the controller instead of the session_store.rb config per Alexis' recommendation and now both sessions are working as expected.

The controller method I used is more or less akin to the following:

```
#/app/controllers/custom_session_controller.rb

before_action :check_session_expiry

def check_session_expiry
  if session[:custom_session_key] && session[:created_at] < 30.minutes.ago
    reset_session
    redirect_to new_custom_session_path, alert: "session expired"
  end
end

#/config/initializers/session_store.rb

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_application_session'
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'custom_session'
```

I found [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261914/rails-cookie-based-sessions-mixing-session-scope-with-expiration-times?rq=1) which was helpful in reaching a solution.